# Delete image by providing its path

Tags: android, image, android-gallery

I would like to delete an image from gallery by providing its path. I've tried couple solutions as the ones below, but none of them work. In the first one I get the log that the file is deleted, but I can still see it in gallery. In the second one I get `Log.d("TAG", "File not found");`

**#1**

```
private void deleteImage() {
    photoOne = mHome.getPhotoOne();
    File fdelete = new File(photoOne);
    if (fdelete.exists()) {
        if (fdelete.delete()) {
            Log.e("-->", "file Deleted :" + photoOne);
            callBroadCast();
        } else {
            Log.e("-->", "file not Deleted :" + photoOne);
        }
    }

}

public void callBroadCast() {
    Log.e("-->", " >= 14");
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getContext(), new String[]{Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()}, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
        /*
         *   (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener#onScanCompleted(java.lang.String, android.net.Uri)
         */
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            Log.e("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
            Log.e("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
        }
    });
}
```

**#2**

```
private void deletePhoto() {
    photoOne = mHome.getPhotoOne();
    File file = new File(photoOne);
    // Set up the projection (we only need the ID)
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};

    // Match on the file path
    String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()};

    // Query for the ID of the media matching the file path
    Uri queryUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContext().getContentResolver();
    Cursor c = contentResolver.query(queryUri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        // We found the ID. Deleting the item via the content provider will also remove the file
        long id = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
        Uri deleteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
        contentResolver.delete(deleteUri, null, null);
    } else {
        // File not found in media store DB
        Log.d("TAG", "File not found");
    }
    c.close();
}
```

**This is how I get the image if it was from camera**

```
private void takePhoto() {
    Intent takePhoto = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = photoPath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),
            getContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",
            photoFile);
    takePhoto.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
    if (whichImage == 1) {
        startActivityForResult(takePhoto, REQUEST_CAMERA_FIRST_CHALLENGE);
    } else if (whichImage == 2) {
        startActivityForResult(takePhoto, REQUEST_CAMERA_SECOND_CHALLENGE);
    }

}

private File photoPath() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    String photoFileName = "PHOTO_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File photoFile = new File(storageDirectory, photoFileName);
    if (whichImage == 1) {
        mPhotoLocation = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
    } else if (whichImage == 2) {
        mPhotoLocation2 = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
    }
    return photoFile;
}
```

**This is how I get the image if it was chosen from gallery**

```
private void selectImage() {
    Intent selectPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    selectPhoto.setType("image/*");
    if (whichImage == 1) {
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(selectPhoto, "Select image"), REQUEST_GALLERY_FIRST_CHALLENGE);
    } else if (whichImage == 2) {
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(selectPhoto, "Select image"), REQUEST_GALLERY_SECOND_CHALLENGE);
    }

}

private String galleryPath(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `ContentResolver#delete` and pass the original `Uri` you got from the picking from the gallery

Comment: Would you care to further explain with a code snippet?

Comment: how do you pick your image? what intent are you using?

Comment: @pskink I've edit my question, please check it.

Comment: so use `Intent#getData()` inside `onActivityResult` method

Comment: You mean `Uri uri = data.getData();` or?

Comment: yes `data.getData()`